# Let a label stay in the foreground

Tags: c#, wpf

I have multiple images that have labels (the UI element) in the bottom right corner. At creation, I first load the images and then the labels, so that the labels are in the foreground (visible). At runtime the order of the images changes - they are repositioned on my Grid. As a result, Labels aren't visible if the image was repositioned, because the Label was created earlier and is therefore behind the image.

Now how do I force the label to stay on top without recreating the labels?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try set `Canvas.ZIndex = 1` to `Label`

Like:

```
this.labelName.SetValue(Canvas.ZIndexProperty, 1);
```

or in `XAML`:

```
<sdk:Label Canvas.ZIndex="1" Content="My Text"/>
```